# How can I display non existing records?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of deals, and I need to check whether they exist in my `DEALS` table, and for each existing deal, display its properties from that table.

I use that query  :

```
select * from deals
where run_id = 2550
and deal_id 
in ('4385601', '4385602', ...);
```

However, I also want to know which deals don't exist in that table. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: The are an endless number of non existing deals. Do you really want them to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all your dealsids in a separate lookup table and use this

```
select t2.*,
case when t1.deal_id is null then 'do not exist' else 'exists' end as status 
from lookup_table as t1 left join deals as t2
on t1.deal_id=t2.deal_id
and t1.deal_id and t2.run_id = 2550
where ('4385601', '4385602', ...)
;
```

Comment: You need that the other way around.  `lookup_table LEFT JOIN deals`.  As currently written you *still* only get a result row for a deal that exists in the `deals` table.

Comment: Oh, and the `run_id = 2550` needs to move to the JOIN as otherwise you'll filter out all of the `do not exist rows` *(because run_id will be NULL by the time you're in the WHERE clause)*.

Comment: I thought of it and already handled that by moved it as part of AND

Comment: But your `deal_id IN (x,y)` should be on the lookup table, not the deal table.

Comment: Yes. I interchanged the underlying tables and not the aliases. Thanks

Comment: It should still be in the where clause.  Currently, if there is a row in the lookup table for `deal 0001` then it doesn't get left joined on to the deals table *(even if it really is in the deals table)* because it's not in the `IN (x,y,z)` list, and so shows up as a `do not exist`.  My understanding is that the OP doesn't want a result for a deal that is not mentioned in the `IN (x,y,z)` list.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.  Any result row has to come from a row that exists somewhere.

So the answer is to create something somewhere that has the full list you want to check.  If you can have a real permanent table listing every valid deal, then that's very simple...

```
SELECT
    all_possible_deals.deal_id
FROM
    all_possible_deals
LEFT JOIN
    deals
        ON  deals.run_id  = 2550
        ON  deals.deal_id = all_possible_deals.deal_id
WHERE
    deals.deal_id IS NULL  -- This is NULL if it exists in [all_possible_deals], but not in [deals]
```

But it may not be practical (or perhaps even possible) to create and/or maintain such a table.

In such a case you can use an in-line-view instead of your `IN (?,?,?)` clause, and use that as your template to left-join on to.

```
SELECT
    all_possible_deals.deal_id
FROM
(
    SELECT '4385601' AS deal_id FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '4385602' AS deal_id FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '4385603' AS deal_id FROM dual
)
    all_possible_deals
LEFT JOIN
    deals
        ON  deals.run_id  = 2550
        ON  deals.deal_id = all_possible_deals.deal_id
WHERE
    deals.deal_id IS NULL  -- This is NULL if it exists in [all_possible_deals], but not in [deals]
```

This involves a little bit of code to programatically generate the `UNION ALL` blocks, but it functionally does what you're asking.

Either way, the principle is always going to be the same.

You can find what is in tableA but not in tableB using a LEFT JOIN and checking for a miss (the NULL check).

But SQL can't create the `rows that are not there`, so the table you LEFT JOIN on to *must* contain the full list of potential existing/missing values.

Answer (score -1):

Another way :-

```
SELECT A.*,
  'Exist'
FROM DEALS A
WHERE A.RUN_ID = 2550
AND A.DEAL_ID IN ('4385601', '4385602',...)
UNION
SELECT B.*,
  'Not Exist'
FROM DEALS B
WHERE B.RUN_ID     = 2550
AND B.DEAL_ID NOT IN ('4385601', '4385602',...);
```

Comment: If there is no row where `RUN_ID = 2550 AND DEAL_ID = '4385601'`, this won't return a row stating that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, in that case, `B.RUN_ID     = 2550`, is not required. but if OP wants output for this perticular run_id then it will be helpful.

Comment: The OP wants to know, using that example, if deal `4385601` doesn't exist in the `DEALS` table.  Your query does ***not*** do that.  Take a simple example; a table with two rows of values `1` and `2`.   Then you query `value IN (0,1)` and union it with `value NOT IN (0,1)`.  Row 1 is in the list, so appears as an EXIST.  Row 2 is not in the list so will appear as a NOT EXIST.  But never will there be a result to say that value 0 does not exist. Your `NOT EXIST` test is `all rows in the table that are not in the IN clause` but the OP wants `all values in the IN clause that are not in the table`